# Calculate probability of winning an ongoing match given probabilities for outcomes

Tags: probability

Team A and Team B are playing a game with $3$ possible results: win, tie and lose.

Team A’s probabilities for each outcome are:

- Win: $0.2$
- Tie: $0.5$
- Lose: $0.3$

The first of the two teams to win $10$ rounds will win the match.

If the game is running and Team B is leading $9$ to $7$, what is the probability that Team A will win the match?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: What happens:

b) if they are at the begin of the game ( $0$ - $0$ ) ?

c) if Team A is leading $5$ to $2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to invoke infinity. Disregard the ties. The next $3$ decisive games must be wins for $A$. The probability that a decisive game is a win for $A$ is $\frac{0.2}{0.2+0.3}=0.4$. Thus the probability that $A$ wins the match is $0.4^3=0.064=6.4\%$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to win, Team A needs to not lose a single time, until it gets $3$ more wins. That is, it needs to get $3$ wins and $k$ ties, for some $k\geq0$, without any losses in between. For each $k$, there are $\binom{k+2}{2}$ orders in which these events can occur, since a “win” event must finalize the match (thanks to [joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki) for pointing out my mistake here). We can then add the probabilities for each $k$ to get $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+2}{2}\left(0.2\right)^3\left(0.5\right)^k=0.008\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+2}{2}\left(0.5\right)^k.$$ We now use the equation $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+n}{n}x^k=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{n+1}},$$ which can be deduced by calculating each coefficient in the expression $$\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^{n+1}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\right)^{n+1}.$$ This yields a final answer of $$0.008\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+2}{2}\left(0.5\right)^k=\frac{0.008}{\left(\frac12\right)^3}=\boxed{6.4\%}.$$

Comment: You're missing a factor $\binom{k+3}3$ (see my answer).

Comment: @joriki Thanks for pointing this out. I’ve fixed my mistake, although the solution lost all of its grace. Your approach is definitely better.

Comment: OK, I've toggled my vote and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I also had arrived at joriki's solution by myself intuition, but I'm interested in the mathematical procedure, as explained by you, for general case of any partial result (as in the question "c").

Comment: @luke2ale My solution can be adapted to the general case, but it will be much easier to take joriki’s approach there too. Ignore ties via conditional probability, and calculate the probability of $W$ wins before $L$ losses, by adding the probabilities for each amount of games $\ell<L$ lost.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want is that the A wins  3 games and B wins none. You can find the probability that A wins after i games i.e. $i^{th}$ game is A’s 3rd win. Sum this over n from 3 to infinity.
Hint: to win after $n^{th}$ game you should win twice in n-1 games and all others are draw.